# Ignored tags cause a page with no questions

Tags: bug

While looking at the bounties I landed on the last page which was empty. I assume that there are enough questions to populate it but my ignored tags list prevents them from being shown. I'm certainly okay with this, but it struck me as odd behavior.

[image: Sorry, there are no questions here]

Comment: There's also the other option of just greying out questions containing an ignored tag.  That makes this less odd.

Comment: Oh, neat. I haven't visited the ignored tags list in a while but maybe I'll flip that switch.

Comment: Yep it's in your profile -> preferences -> ignored tags.  I would guess that that link in your picture also navigates to the same preferences page.

Comment: I found it and set it to grey them out. Thanks for that :)